# What is the incentive for a participating node in a "Proof of Stake" consensus model of Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I am following [this](https://www.coindesk.com/short-guide-blockchain-consensus-protocols) article to understand the different alternative consensus models. Here it mentions:

> no coin creation (mining) exists in proof of stake. Instead, all the
>   coins exist from day one

It further mentions:

> In proof of stake, your chance of being picked to create the next
>   block depends on the fraction of coins in the system you own

Now, my question is - what is the incentive for the participating node (other than the one with the highest stake) considering no new coins are minted?

Why would a node participate in the blockchain knowing that it isn't the highest stakeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ethereum's proposed future PoS implementation (Casper) as an example, the reward would be **transaction fees**.

Since in a Proof-of-Stake system there are **no** newly minted coins, as you noted, the idea is to incentivize the stakeholders by rewarding them with the transaction fees for the block they win.

You may note that the current Proof-of-Work system gives ***both*** a minting reward AND transaction fees to the winning miner, where Proof-of-Stake only gives the latter. That's the key difference.

In preparation for that event Ethereum is already planning to reduce the mining reward for the current PoW implementation over time - giving the community an adjustment period to get used to the "new way of things."

It should also be noted that a "transaction fee only" system is the end-game of Bitcoin as well once the block rewards halve out to fractional satoshis, though it will stay Proof-of-Work.

Some source info:
https://blockgeeks.com/guides/proof-of-work-vs-proof-of-stake/
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQs

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this line-  **"transaction fee only" system is the end-game of Bitcoin as well once the block rewards halve out to fractional satoshis, though it will stay Proof-of-Work.**